# Can we use Xamarin SkiaSharp for cross platform desktop form development in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, winforms, xamarin, .net-core, skiasharp

I want to know Can we use **SkiaSharp** for cross platform desktop form development like windows forms development but for cross platform purposes ?

something like wxWidgets in C++ Can we use **SkiaSharp** in .NET Core for desktop development ?

Can we have forms,controls and ... by **SkiaSharp** ?

Is **SkiaSharp** could be an alternative to the Windows Forms but in cross platforms ?

Answer (score 2):

SkiaSharp and Skia is just for 2D rendering. If there would be a cross platform UI framework for .NET Core, that thing would have to be more than Skia.

Currently the nearest way is Xamarin.Forms, which already supports iOS/Android/UWP/Tizen/macOS, while its Linux support (based on GTK#) and Windows desktop support (based on WPF) are coming (announced at Build 2017 in https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/B8099).

Forget about Windows Forms, as it is the least portable framework to go.

Comment: ,  so you say We will have WPF in .NET Core too ? Yes ? Do you have a reference ? I need a cross platform solution for desktop GUI programming.

Comment: Revised the answer and added the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider Avalonia UI. It actually uses SkiaSharp for rendering, and it is cross-platform, free and open-source. It supports at least Windows, Linux, macOS, and is said to support Android and iOS (I have not personally tried it yet). The API structure resembles WPF significantly.